# How can i create this search program?

Tags: software-rec, download, google-search, cross-platform, open-source

I want to make a program that searches google periodically for images relating to or containing highly specific text and images, downloads them, and outputs them with the right trigger for Windows, Linux and Mac

Less vaguely, I'm trying to make a mod that matches and downloads online fan-art for Dwarf fortress with the detailed description that inspired it. [Take these drawings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRHp6.jpg). There are many more like them, and they usually correspond to the original text the game generated, such as

> "A towering scaly warthog. It has two long, hanging tails and it has a bloated body. Its dark indigo scales are oval-shaped and set far apart. Beware its poisonous gas! Bora was associated with water, torture and caverns."

Tools exist that monitor the games output, so that's easily done. I need advice on automatically searching, downloading and outputting images.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a javascript background you can build a web crawler with nodejs + phantomjs. it is actually very easy if you are into programming.

if you don't want to code have a look at iMacros for Chrome, you can automate tasks with your browser

Comment: I need a simple web scraper. Thanks, now i know the language to use.